# Buscar intervalos iguais em uma lista

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, visual-basic-6

Sou usuaria iniciante e tentei quase tudo mas não consegui resolver a questão e gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar.

Numa coluna tenho valores numericos e gostaria de comparar os intervalos de quatro células "A2:A5" com "A3:A6", depois com "A4:A7", e assim sucessivamente ate o final da planilha; fazendo o mesmo processo para "A3:A6" com "A4:A7", depois com "A5:A8", e depois com todas os outros intervalos de "quatro celulas".

Sendo os valores e a ordem das "quatro de células" comparadas iguais gostaria que retornasse em outra coluna dizendo quais são os intervalos iguais.

Sei que esse processo pode ser feito "manualmente" intervalo por intervalo mas gostaria de "automatiza-lo". A ajuda será muito bem vinda de preferencia no Excel mas pode ser em VBA mesmo.

Abraços.

obs.: segue imagem ilustrativa.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: já pensou em refazer essa logica pra outra forma, poderia dizer qual intuito disso?

Comment: ela representa a medida semanal de uma substancia em plantas ao longo de um ano e quero encontrar os intervalos iguais para saber em que semanas ocorreram. não sei como refazer essa logica de outra forma e pensei em Excel(VBA) pois os dados estão nesse formato. se tiver alguma sugestao ficarei agradecida!

Comment: Oi Tati, a solução que apresentei em Excel para o teu caso era o que você esperava? Atendeu ou te ajudou de alguma forma? Se sim, por favor, marque a resposta. Há um "Check" abaixo das setas de votação do lado esquerdo superior de cada resposta para você indicar a que melhor te atendeu. Isto faz parte do processo de perguntas e respostas aqui da comunidade, além da votação em perguntas e respostas...

Comment: Oi Leo...desculpa mas so pude acessar agora...e aparentemente resolve o problema sim...vou testar e retorno comentarios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Solução** no **Excel** pode ser feita assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A célula **A1** deve ter o valor 4 (quatro), pois é a quantidade de itens a comparar (não coloque outro valor aqui por hora, ver as observações abaixo)

A célula **D1** apresenta o número da última linha com dados em sua tabela (automaticamente)

A coluna **B** é apenas para separar os dados visualmente.

A coluna **C** apresenta uma configuração padrão para cada conjunto de quatro valores a serem comparados, incluindo o valor da própria linha e os três valores seguintes (adaptar aqui caso venha a usar uma outra quantidade de itens a comparar, ver as observações abaixo).

A coluna **D** apresenta o número da linha de dados

A coluna **E** apresenta o número da linha da primeira ocorrência na sequência de dados da faixa de valores correspondente aos valores da própria linha, quando houver repetição na tabela (ver observações)

A coluna **F** apresenta cada ocorrência na forma que solicitou

A coluna **H** mostra uma célula específica

A coluna **I** descreve a função desta célula ou apresenta sua fórmula

**Observações**

1. Caso a célula A1 seja alterada para uma quantidade de valores diferente de quatro, as fórmulas da coluna C precisarão ser adaptadas.
2. A coluna D apresenta uma única ocorrência por linha, a próxima ocorrência imediatamente seguinte à linha atual, não apresentando outras ocorrências caso existam, no entanto, se existirem, a linha com a segunda ocorrência apontará para a linha da terceira ocorrência e assim por diante...
3. A cada nova linha de dados incluída ou para várias novas linhas incluídas, as fórmulas contidas nas colunas C, D, E e F devem ser copiadas e coladas em cada uma delas, para isso, basta copiar a faixa de C até F de uma das linhas anteriores.
4. No exemplo apresentado novos valores faram acrescidos aos seus para mostrar duas ocorrências de duas sequências distintas (linhas 8 e 27) e ao mesmo tempo, duas ocorrências de uma mesma sequência (linhas 2, 10 e 22)

Estas são as fórmulas para copiar e colar:

```
=MÁXIMO(D2:D99999)

=A2&"|"&A3&"|"&A4&"|"&A5

=LIN()

=SE(OU(NÃO(ÉNÚM(INDIRETO("A"&(D2+$A$1-1))));ÉERROS(PROCV(C2;INDIRETO("C"&(D2+1)&":D"&$D$1);2;FALSO)));"";PROCV(C2;INDIRETO("C"&(D2+1)&":D"&$D$1);2;FALSO))

=SE(ÉNÚM(E2);"A"&D2&":A"&(D2+$A$1-1)&" = A"&E2&":A"&(E2+$A$1-1);"")
```

Faça o teste mesmo para uma planilha com muitos dados, tenho planilhas bem mais complexas que essa e com inúmeros dados (linhas e colunas) e inúmeras fórmulas e não há espera ou atraso para o processamento de cada novo dado inserido (com o cálculo automático ativo), pode ser que ocorra o mesmo para você.

Comment: Muito boa resposta! :)

Comment: Ainda vou testar para ver se adequa a minha necessidade (aparentemente sim!)...e achei a resposta excelente porque apesar de parecer um problema simples envolve comparacoes complexas...parabens Leo!

Comment: Obrigado Tati, espero ter contribuído com tua pesquisa!

Comment: Sensacional Leo! Apesar de parecer simples, não seria trivial faze-lo diretamente no Excel, como bem disse o Luiz! Tive que fazer algumas pequenas adaptações mas no geral serviu exatamente para minha necessidade. Agora posso partir para analise dos dados em minha pesquisa. Sen sua ajuda eu demoraria muuuito para conseguir! Obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

Eu não acho que seja trivial (talvez sequer possível) fazer isso diretamente com fórmulas do Excel pois envolve uma busca interativa. Assim, creio que a melhor forma seja mesmo usando VBA.

Um exemplo de função que faz isso é a seguinte:

```
Function findEqual(ByRef oRange As Range, ByVal iComparingSize As Integer) As String

    ' Só funciona com uma só coluna no range
    If oRange.Columns.Count <> 1 Then
         findEqual = CVErr(xlErrValue)
         Exit Function
    End If

    Dim iComp1 As Integer, iComp2 As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim bEqual As Boolean

    ' "Ponteiro" 1: varre do começo ao fim do intervalo dado
    For iComp1 = 1 To (oRange.Rows().Count - iComparingSize)

        ' "Ponteiro" 2: varre da linha seguinte à do ponteiro 1 ao fim do intervalo dado
        For iComp2 = iComp1 + 1 To (oRange.Rows().Count - iComparingSize)

            ' Compara os n valores seguintes a cada "ponteiro"
            bEqual = True
            For i = 0 To iComparingSize - 1
                If oRange.Cells(iComp1 + i).Value <> oRange.Cells(iComp2 + i).Value Then
                    bEqual = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

            ' Se forem todos iguais, encontrou o que buscava!
            ' Logo, retorna uma string com os endereços dos dois intervalos comparados
            If bEqual Then
                findEqual = oRange.Cells(iComp1).Address() + ":" + oRange.Cells(iComp1 + iComparingSize - 1).Address() + " = "
                findEqual = findEqual + oRange.Cells(iComp2).Address() + ":" + oRange.Cells(iComp2 + iComparingSize - 1).Address()
                Exit Function
            End If

        Next

    Next

    ' Se chegou aqui, não encontrou nada igual
    findEqual = "Não há intervalos iguais!"

End Function
```

Para usar essa função, coloque-a em um módulo novo dentro do código da planilha, e chame-a em uma célula passando como primeiro parâmetro o intervalo com os dados a serem analisados (no seu exemplo, `A2:A17`) e como segundo parâmetro o tamanho da "janela" de busca (isto é, quantos elementos precisam ser iguais - no seu exemplo, `4`). Por exemplo, coloque na célula `H10` o seguinte:

```
=findEqual(A2:A17;4)
```

Ela produz o resultado esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A função funciona com três laços. Os dois primeiros são como "ponteiros" que marcam o início das regiões que estão sendo comparadas, e o terceiro laço (mais interno) é o que de fato faz a comparação.

Observe que apesar de funcionar esse algoritmo tende a ter um desempenho ruim para listas muito longas. Além disso, essa função de exemplo retorna uma string para visualização, mas talvez seja mais útil pra você uma função que retorne uma matriz com as duas regiões encontradas. Não sei, vai depender do seu uso. Nesse caso, [o comentário do colega @Thalles](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/156230/buscar-intervalos-iguais-em-uma-lista#comment322302_156230) faz todo o sentido: talvez seja importante você repensar ou rediscutir a sua necessidade/problema do zero.

Comment: um dos meus medos era exatamente esse: a lista é longa! ela representa a medida semanal de uma substancia em plantas ao longo de um ano
e quero encontrar os intervalos iguais para saber em que semanas ocorreram. não faço a menor ideia de como repensar isso e pensei em Excel(VBA) pois os dados estão nesse formato.

Comment: Bom, testa. Se é uma medida semanal ao longo de um ano, não serão tantos valores assim (um ano tem 52 semanas aproximadamente). Talvez funcione suficientemente bem. Outra abordagem que pode lhe ser útil é reduzir os valores. Você pode, por exemplo, calcular a diferença entre cada par de valores (semana 2 - semana 1, depois semana 3 - semana 2, e assim sucessivamente), e depois tentar encontrar padrões nessa diferença. Talvez até mesmo só gerando um gráfico da variação da substância já te ajude a notar visualmente os padrões.

Comment: Eu ja havia pensado em avaliar visualmente mas como preciso da correspondencia exata busquei uma avaliacao apartir dos dados. Vou testar essa e as outras possibilidades que voce sugeriu que esclareceram muita coisa. Obrigada!